# level=error msg="Cannot create service: subset not found"

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

Running traefik on kuberntes and trying trying to create ingress to deployment in dev namespace

time="2021-03-12T05:44:44Z" level=error msg="Cannot create service: subset not found"  namespace=dev servicePort=80 serviceName=baseui providerName=kubernetes ingress=devingress

Comment: There are probably several different ways in which this error can arise. For me, it just happened because I had an ingress with no rules and only a default `backend` section. Once I added an http-based rule to my ingress, it picled up properly.

Comment: did you found the solution?